# Apache status code returning 406 error with variables within href

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess

Howdie do,

So, when the following URL is clicked, I receive a 406 error:

```
<a href='index.php?page=tools&section=open&model=$server[Model]&desc=$server[Description]'> List of Open servers </a>
```

Now, I know the 406 error means the request headers accept received a response that it wasn't expecting.

However, checking the headers shows that the correction information was sent.

Is there anything wrong with my URL that's causing the 406 status to be returned?

Just in case you're wondering, the htaccess looks like:

```
RewriteRule ^tools/open/(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?page=tools&section=open&model=$1&desc=$2 [L]
```

Comment: You have a *huge* security hole here. You need to validate and sanitize your GET parameters.

Comment: your rewrited url should and with slash (/) according to htaccess, but you should get and 404 error instead of infinite loop, add a slash here : window.location = base + "tools/open/"+model+"/"+desc+'/';

Comment: `index.php?page=tools$section=open&model=$1&desc=$2` -> `index.php?page=tools&section=open&model=$1&desc=$2`

Comment: I've added the / into the windows.location and updated the htaccess to index.php?page=tools&section=open&model=$1&desc=$2. However, still the same issue.  Why would I need to validate and sanitize the GET parameters? They won't be changing as you just link directly